# unzipping a file in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, unzip, fso

I'm trying to use an unzip/zip class. I need to unzip a zip file after upload. i modified "sleep" function to check "controller" function per intSeconds value and added "controller" function to check file count on target folder. You can see a code part below.

zip file is successfully unzipped with this functions but page progress never ending. i need to restart iis after to use this function.

Original code on : [Class CompressedFolder](http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/class-creating-compressed-folders-natively-258394.html)

```
<%
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFso   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Function ExtractAll(strZipFile, strFolder)
        If Not objFso.FolderExists(strFolder) Then objFso.CreateFolder(strFolder)
        intCount = objShell.NameSpace(strFolder).Items.Count
        Set colItems = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items
        objShell.NameSpace(strFolder).CopyHere colItems, 8
        Sleep 5000,strFolder,intCount + colItems.Count
    End Function        

    function controller(path,filesCountMust)
       dim stat:stat=False
       set fold = objFso.getFolder(path)
       set files = fold.files
       if filesCountMust=files.count then
          stat=True
       end if
       set files = nothing 
       set fold = nothing
       controller=stat
    end function

    Sub Sleep(intSeconds,path,filesCountMust)
        dblSeconds = intSeconds / 1000
        If dblSeconds < 1 Then dblSeconds = 1
        dteStart = Now()
        dteEnd = DateAdd("s", dblSeconds, dteStart)  
        do While dteEnd>=Now()
           if dteEnd=Now() then
              if controller(path,filesCountMust)=true then 
                 exit do
              else
                 Sleep intSeconds,path,filesCountMust
              end if
           end if
        loop
    End Sub

    Set objShell = Nothing
    Set objFso   = Nothing
```

%>

Comment: Are you able to step through code in a debugger? The infinite execution you report is only possible if `controller` always returns false (i.e. always calling the recursion)

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem

```
if dteEnd=Now() then
```

Only if dteEnd is *exactly* the same as Now() (to the millisecond) will it be able to step into the controller section and head towards the exit do, it doesn't and goes into a recursive loop (back into the sleep function)

Try this instead:

```
do While dteEnd>=Now()
   if dteEnd>=Now() then
      if controller(path,filesCountMust)=true then 
         exit do
      else
         Sleep intSeconds,path,filesCountMust
      end if
   end if
loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but given that I found this this Stack Overflow question and github solution in the same search result. I thought this might be a good shot as a solution to your problem.

https://github.com/rcdmk/aspZip